# jQuery chosen set focus after change

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-chosen

How can I set the focus after `jQuery` `chosen` fired?

I tried this code, but didn't work:

HTML:

```
<select id="producer_id">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="product" id="product">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#producer_id').chosen().change(function() {
     $('#product').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set correct ID and use this:

```
$('#producer_id').on('change',function() {
     $('#product').focus();
});
```

Comment: sorry but this isn't work... I need to change th focus _after_ the change... not before.

Comment: try to replace 'focus' to 'keyup', but it firing only one event. change event on input element fires after focus out

Comment: sorry, I belived it is clear... the `#producer_id` is a select field using jQuery chosen plugin.

Comment: replace <select id="prodicer_id"> to <select id="producer_id">